# Laravel Soft Deletes dosent work in one table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

I am trying to make soft deletes in my DB tables but it fails in one table. I made same things with other tables but only in one it dosen't work. When i click delete in view it deletes row in data base. I will show code of soft delete for this table and have hope that you will help me.

This is my migration for it:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class Invoices extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('invoicenumber')->nullable();
            $table->date('invoicedate')->nullable();
            $table->date('selldate')->nullable();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('form_id')->unsigned()->nullable();                        
            $table->integer('currency_id')->unsigned()->nullable();            
            $table->integer('proform_id')->unsigned()->nullable(); 
            $table->string('paymentmethod')->nullable();
            $table->date('paymentdate')->nullable();
            $table->string('status')->nullable();
            $table->string('comments')->nullable();
            $table->string('city')->nullable();
            $table->string('paid')->nullable();
            $table->string('autonumber')->nullable();
            $table->string('automonth')->nullable();
            $table->string('autoyear')->nullable();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('PKWIU')->nullable();
            $table->string('quantity')->nullable();
            $table->string('unit')->nullable();            
            $table->string('netunit')->nullable();
            $table->string('nettotal')->nullable();
            $table->string('VATrate')->nullable();
            $table->string('grossunit')->nullable();
            $table->string('grosstotal')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->time('deleted_at')->nullable(); 

        });
        
        Schema::table('invoices', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('users')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');           

          
            $table->foreign('form_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('forms')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');                
    

            $table->foreign('currency_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('currencys')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
 
            
            $table->foreign('proform_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('proforms')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');

        });
             
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('invoices');
    }
}
```

This is model for invoice. Invoice.php

```
<?php


namespace App;

use Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Sortable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Invoice extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *  
     * @var array
     */
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Sortable;
    
    
    protected $table = 'invoices';

    
    protected $fillable = [
        'invoicenumber', 'invoicedate', 'id', 'selldate', 'user_id', 'paymentmethod', 
        'paymentdate', 'status', 'comments', 'city', 'paid',  'autonumber', 'automonth', 'autoyear', 'name',
         'PKWIU', 'quantity', 'unit', 'netunit', 'nettotal',
         'VATrate', 'grossunit', 'grosstotal', 'form_id', 'currency_id',
    ];
    
    public $sortable = [     'invoicenumber', 'invoicedate', 'id', 'selldate', 
    'user_id', 'paymentmethod', 'paymentdate', 'status', 'comments', 'grosstotal', 'nettotal', 'form_id', 'currency_id',];
    
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    
        public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

        public function form()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Form');
    }

         public function currency()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Currency');
    }
   
        public function proform()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Proform');
    } 
    
}
```

InvoiceController.php

```
<?php
    
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Sortable;    
use App\Invoice;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Proform;
use App\Form;
use App\Currency;
use DB;     
    
class InvoiceController extends Controller
{ 
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    function __construct()
    {
         $this->middleware('permission:product-list|product-create|product-edit|product-delete', ['only' => ['index','show']]);
         $this->middleware('permission:product-create', ['only' => ['create','store']]);
         $this->middleware('permission:product-edit', ['only' => ['edit','update']]);
         $this->middleware('permission:product-delete', ['only' => ['destroy']]);
    }
    
    public function search4(Request $request)
    {

    $user = User::all('showname','id');
    $invoices = Invoice::sortable()->paginate(5);
        
    $query = DB::table('users')
            ->join('invoices', 'users.id', '=', 'invoices.user_id');
            
        
    $search = $request->get('search');
    $requestData = ['showname'];
        
    /* $query = Proform::query(); */
    foreach ($requestData as $field){
    $query->orWhere($field, 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
    }
    $data2=$query->paginate(5);
    return view('invoices.index', ['invoices' => $data2, 'user'=> $user])->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user = User::all('showname','id');
        $invoices = Invoice::sortable()->paginate(5);
        return view('invoices.index',compact('invoices', 'user'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }
    
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {   $users = User::all('showname','id');
        $forms = Form::all('id', 'form');
        $currencys = Currency::all('id', 'currency', 'course');
        return view('invoices.create')->with('users', $users, 'forms', 'currencys');
    }
    
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'invoicedate' => 'required',
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'selldate' => 'required',
            'paymentdate' => 'required',
            'paymentmethod' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required',
            'comments' => 'nullable',
            'city' => 'nullable',
            'paid' => 'nullable',
            'name' => 'required',
            'PKWIU' => 'nullable',
            'quantity' => 'required',
            'unit' => 'required',
            'netunit' => 'required',
            'nettotal' => 'required',
            'VATrate' => 'required',
            'grossunit' => 'required',
            'grosstotal' => 'required',
            

            
        ]);
        
        

        Invoice::create($request->all());
    
        return redirect()->route('invoices.index')
                        ->with('success','Invoice created successfully.');
    }
    
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Invoice $invoice)
    {
        return view('invoices.show',compact('invoice'));
    }
    
    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Invoice $invoice)
    {
        $users = User::all('showname','id');
        $forms = Form::all('id', 'form');
        $currencys = Currency::all('id', 'currency', 'course');
        return view('invoices.edit',compact('invoice', 'users', 'forms', 'currencys'));
    }
    
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Invoice $invoice)
    {
         request()->validate([
            'invoicedate' => 'required',
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'selldate' => 'required',
            'paymentdate' => 'required',
            'paymentmethod' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required',
            'comments' => 'nullable',
            'city' => 'nullable',
            'paid' => 'nullable',
            'name' => 'required',
            'PKWIU' => 'nullable',
            'quantity' => 'required',
            'unit' => 'required',
            'netunit' => 'required',
            'nettotal' => 'required',
            'VATrate' => 'required',
            'grossunit' => 'required',
            'grosstotal' => 'required',
        ]);
    
        $invoice->update($request->all());
    
        return redirect()->route('invoices.index')
                        ->with('success','Invoice updated successfully');
    }
    
    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Product  $product
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Invoice $invoice)
    {
        $invoice->delete();
    
        return redirect()->route('invoices.index')
                        ->with('success','Invoice deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
Route::get('/', function(){
return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('home');
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
Route::get('/search', 'UserController@search');
Route::get('/search2', 'ProductController@search2');
Route::get('/search3', 'ProformController@search3');
Route::get('/search4', 'InvoiceController@search4');

Route::post('/duplicate', 'ProformController@duplicate')->name('proforms.duplicate');
Route::get('data', 'UserController@index');
Route::get('posts', 'PostController@index');
Route::get('/prodview', 'TestController@prodfunct');

Route::resource('roles', 'RoleController');
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
Route::resource('permissions', 'PermissionController');
Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
Route::resource('invoices', 'InvoiceController');

Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');
Route::resource('invoices', 'InvoiceController');
Route::resource('proforms', 'ProformController');
});
```

View:

```
@extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Zarządzanie fakturami</h2>
            </div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
<form action="/search4" method="get">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="search" name="search" class="form-control">
<span class="input-group-prepend">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Wyszukaj</button>
</span>
</div>
</form>
</div>  


            <div class="pull-right">
                @can('product-create')
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('invoices.create') }}"> Utwórz nową fakturę</a>
                @endcan
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif


    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('id', 'Numer')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('invoicnumber', 'Numer faktury')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('invoicedate', 'Data wystawienia')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('user_id', 'Kontrachent')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('selldate', 'Data sprzedaży')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('paymentdate', 'Termin płatności')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('status', 'Status')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('nettotal', 'Netto razem')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('grosstotal', 'Brutto razem')</th>
            <th width="280px">Akcja</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($invoices as $invoice)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
            <td>{{ $invoice->invoicenumber }}</td>
            <td>{{ $invoice->invoicedate }}</td>
            <td>{{ $invoice->user->showname  ??  $invoice->showname }}</td>
            <td>{{ $invoice->selldate }}</td>
            <td>{{ $invoice->paymentdate }}</td>
            <td>{{ $invoice->status }}</td>
            <td>{{ $invoice->nettotal }}</td>
            <td>{{ $invoice->grosstotal }}</td>


            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('invoices.destroy',$invoice->id) }}" method="POST">
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('invoices.show',$invoice->id) }}">Więcej</a>
                    @can('product-edit')
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('invoices.edit',$invoice->id) }}">Edytuj</a>
                    @endcan


                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    @can('product-delete')
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Usuń</button>
                    @endcan
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>

{!! $invoices ?? ''->appends(request()->except('page'))->render() !!}
 


<p class="text-center text-primary"><small>ARTplus 2020</small></p>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 2):

You must to use `$table->softDeletes();` instead of `$table->time('deleted_at')->nullable();`.

`softDeletes()` method used `timestamp` instead of `time` format date. Maybe it will solve your problem;

Comment: it didn't helped

Comment: @PiotrŚwitlicki Did you run ```php artisan migrate:refresh```?
Be noticed it will clear the content in your database.